# Dynamic NavigationURL in ASP.NET taken from MySQL database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, data-binding

I'm trying to make an extra field in a ListView control in ASP.NET to link to another page using the ID from that entry in the URL.

Currently trying

```
<asp:HyperLink 
        ID="HLDisasterDetails" 
     runat="server" 
      Text="Disaster Details" 
   NavigateUrl=<% "~/DisasterDetails.aspx?Disaster_ID=" & 
                Eval("Disaster_ID") %> />
```

which doesn't work.

Help would be greatly appreciated

~M

Answer (score 0):

Add a # Symbol

```
    NavigateUrl=<%# "~/DisasterDetails.aspx?Disaster_ID=" &                 
    Eval("Disaster_ID") %> />
```

-RVR